# Dynamic Div Disappears After Refreshing The Page

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

So I wrote this code to dynamically upload the user content to the main page, but whenever I refresh the page the div disappears.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "post_blog.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      username: username,
      title: title,
      idea: idea
    },
    success: function(info) {
        $('#posthandler').prepend("<div class=\"col-md-10 col-lg-8 mx-auto\" style=\"border: 1px solid #0f799e; border-radius: 5px;\"><h4><label>" + username + "</label></h4> <h4><label>" + title + "</label></h4><div>" + idea + "</div> </div> <br>");
        $("#username").val("");
        $("#idea").val("");
        $("#title").val("");
    }
  });
```

Comment: Please show us code

Comment: You need to store the dynamic div on your server so that when the page is reloaded the div is output with the rest of the page.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your comment  can you write the snippet of the code for me please.

Answer (score 0):

You client (browser) needs some way to retrieve data from your server to display to get the new uploaded content.

When you call:

```
$('posthandler').prepend(....);
```

you are only showing the  locally, and when you refresh the page, it disappears. In order to have persistent data, you need to store it on your server. If you are using a PHP templating language, you need to learn how to set up your HTML page to retrieve the values when the page is served.

One example is you need make a post request to get the uploaded blog post when the page loads by creating an endpoint on your server that returns blog post data to the user (browser):

```
$( document ).ready(
  $.ajax({
      url: "get_post_blog.php",
      method: "POST",
      success: function(info) {
          $('#posthandler').prepend("<div class=\"col-md-10 col-lg-8 mx-auto\" style=\"border: 1px solid #0f799e; border-radius: 5px;\"><h4><label>" + username + "</label></h4> <h4><label>" + title + "</label></h4><div>" + idea + "</div> </div> <br>");
          $("#username").val("");
          $("#idea").val("");
          $("#title").val("");
      }
    });

)
```